# Save image from axes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save, image, axes, matlab-figure

I generate a picture in an axes that is called newIM when I click on the apply button.
Now, I want to save this new picture in a jpg, gif, bmp or whatever file when I push the save button.

This is what I had:

```
pathname = 'D:\pictures\';
filename = 'Test.bmp';
both = strcat(pathname, filename);
imshow(both);
imsave('test','*.jpg')
```

But this is only for a Test.bmp and not for the picture in newIM.

How can I make this variable?

Comment: You just want to save a figure?  Use the `Save As...` item from the file menu and choose the desired format.  Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @reve_etrange `Save As...` saves the figure including boundaries and labels. It takes a different approach to save only the axes contents.

Comment: @user1008374: how exactly do you "generate a picture in an axes"? please be more specific

Answer (score 5):

Use *getfame*:

```
F = getframe(gcf);
image(F.cdata);
imwrite(F.cdata, 'file.jpg');
```

Comment: i got this now
set(handles.newIm,'HandleVisibility','ON');
axes(handles.newIm); 
imsave();

Answer (score 0):

If it's in some gui or other plots I usually use `copyobj` to copy the axes containing the picture and add them to a new (usually hidden) figure window.